# Java: saving files with snapshots

Tags: java, thumbnails, windows-shell

I was wondering: if you have an application to create math graphics such as matlab, and you want your saved files to have an snapshot when showed at the file explorer of your OS (such as autocad dwg files for example)... how could you do that? is this even possible?

Comment: I am sure it is possible, I just do not know how :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's called thumbnails, the Windows Shell extension. I believe you cannot use Java to make the extensions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx